# Excel VBA: Selecting a checkbox whose name is in a cell

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have a list of of checkbox names as text in cells (column C) and i want to save that name to ChkB and then link the cell to the checkbox. When ever i run this i get an "invalid use of property" error at the ChkB= line. I tried looking this up and i'm not finding anything helpful. Hoping someone can help me out.

**Updated line 4.. now i have a new error on line 5 "Method or data member not found"
** P.S. i thought i should mention i'm using VBA in a word doc to edit an excel file.
Perhaps this effects the LinkedCell command? (it is referencing the worksheet so it knows to do this bit in excel)
** Updated again... on the line where i set ChkB, i'm getting a type mismatch error

```
 Dim ChkB As CheckBox

 For k = 2 To 9
            Set ChkB = Sheets("SheetA").Shapes(Range("C" & k).Value)
            .LinkedCell = "C" & k
 Next k
```

UPDATE: Solved it. Thanks Tim Williams

```
Dim ChkB As CheckBox
Dim e as string

For k = 2 To 9
        e = Range("C" & k).Text
        Sheets("SheetA").Checkboxes(e).LinkedCell = "SheetA!C" & k
Next k
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `Set` on line 4.

Comment: Thanks... now the issue is line 5. "Method or data member not found"... is LinkedCell not a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sheets("SheetA").Checkboxes(Range("C" & k).Value).LinkedCell="C" & k
```

Comment: no cigar... new error "Unable to get the CheckBoxes property of the Worksheet class"